# Computing the median of salaries under each manager in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, median

I have a BigQuery table with columns: `employee`, `salary`, `gender`, `manager`. I would like to compute the median, within each team (so, for each manager), of female employees' salaries.

I have tried using the `PERCENTILE_CONT(..., 0.5)` [navigation function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#percentile_cont) but it seems it does not support `GROUP BY`

This is my query:

```
SELECT
  manager,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(salary,
    0.5) OVER() AS median_of_women_salaries
FROM
  employees_table
WHERE
  gender = 'woman'
GROUP BY
  manager
```

What I get is the error message:

**"SELECT list expression references column `salary` which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [.:.]"**

As a result, I would like to get a table with columns `manager` and `median_of_women_salaries` that would show the median of females salaries under each manager.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an existing shared UDF:

```
SELECT
  manager,
  fhoffa.x.median(ARRAY_AGG(salary)) AS median_of_women_salaries
FROM employees_table
WHERE gender = 'woman'
GROUP BY manager
```

- https://medium.com/@hoffa/new-in-bigquery-persistent-udfs-c9ea4100fd83
- https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=fhoffa&d=x&r=median&page=routine

[image]